# Selenium Webdriver v3.141 supported Chrome and Firefox versions

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium (C#) Webdriver v3.141 and using the latest versions of Chrome (v114) and Firefox (v114) browsers to run tests.

Things (elements/locators/wait etc) that were previously working on Chrome and Firefox (before v100) are randomly failing without any change done to the code.
Is there any compatible browser version list with each Selenium version available? I have already checked the Selenium website but I am unable to find one.

Comment: Selenium is compatible with any modern browser version. The browser **driver** version has to match the browser version you are using.

Comment: It's matched, however, I am started seeing weird issues without changing any code. The only change that happened are browser version updates.